# jQuery Object has No Method and this

Tags: jquery, object, methods, this

I sorted through the top 12 or so questions without coming to an answer, so here's my particular state:

```
function someFunction( elem ){
    var someVar = elem.siblings(':input[type=radio]').attr('name');
    console.log( group );
}

$('my-element').on('click', $(this), someFunction );
```

This give me a 'Object has not method siblings' error. Originally I had the contents of somefunction inside the .on event handler as a function and things worked fine. I understand that I'm missing something with regards to how jQuery is casting $(this) about, but I'm uncertain as to what it may be. I can dump elem from inside someFunction and see the element I'm after, but I cannot manipulate it.

Any pointers?

Comment: Looking at the docs may be beneficial. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: The jQuery docs were my first stop, but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function someFunction(){
    var someVar = $(this).siblings(':input[type=radio]').attr('name');
    console.log( group ); // <-- whats group??
}

$('my-element').on('click', someFunction);
```

**note:** my method will attach an event handler on each 'my-element'.

Comment: This was it, thank you. I had read in the doc that jQuery passes a data object along to the event handler, though thought there was more I had to do from there. This works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bind` instead.

```
function someFunction(){
    var someVar = $(this).siblings(':input[type=radio]').attr('name');

}

$('my-element').bind('click', someFunction);
```